# Setting alternative records true if its even count else leave last record

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have an attendance list like this.

**problem:** I need to set `In` and `Out` alternatively. but if I have only 3 records then I need to set 0 record `In` true. 1 record `out` is true. and 3 record has is both `In` `Out` is false. i tried like this its working fine. but i was checking is there any better way with linq.

```
ObservableCollection<EmployeeAttandance> attendancesPerDay = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeAttandance>();
if (attendancesPerDay.Count % 2 == 0)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var attendance in attendancesPerDay)
    {
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
            attendance.In = true;
        else
            attendance.Out = true;
        counter++;
    }
}
else
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var attendance in attendancesPerDay)
    {
        if (attendancesPerDay.IndexOf(attendance) == attendancesPerDay.Count - 1)
            continue;
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
            attendance.In = true;
        else
            attendance.Out = true;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aron check if list count is odd or even odd don't set anything for the first item. and set alternatively in and out else just set in and out one loop right.

Comment: Okay...let me rephrase that. Complete the code body: `for(var i = attendancesPerDay.Count -1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }`

Comment: My appologies, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the is my conclusion from your code: you want to set even indices' `In` to `true` and odd indices' `Out` to `true`, and if the list length is even then leave both `In` and `Out` `false` for the last record?

Comment: @mshwf every `In` should have `out` lets say i have 4 records then no problem `0 is in= true` `1 is out=true` `2 in = true` `3 out =true` done. in case I got only 3 records then `0 in =true` `1 out =true` `2 both in and out is false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try assign `In` and `Out` for a *previous* (not *current*) item:

```
  bool isEven = true;
  EmployeeAttandance prior = null;

  foreach (EmployeeAttandance item in attendancesPerDay) {
    if (prior != null) {
      if (isEven)
        prior.Out = true;
      else
        prior.In = true;
    }

    isEven = !isEven;
    prior = item;
  }

  if (isEven && prior != null) // should we assign anything to the last item?
    prior.Out = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
var isIn = false;
var isOut = false;
int attendanceCount = attendancesPerDay.Count;
var set1 = attendancesPerDay.Take(attendanceCount % 2 == 0 ? attendanceCount : attendanceCount - 1).ToList();
var set2 = attendancesPerDay.Skip(attendanceCount % 2 == 0 ? attendanceCount : attendanceCount - 1).ToList();
set1.ForEach(a => {
    if(!isIn)
    {
        isIn = true;
        a.In = isIn;
        isOut = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isOut = true;
        a.Out = isOut;
        isIn = false;
    }
});

set1.AddRange(set2);
```